# Estimation of PSD from timeseries

Tags: python, fft, time-series

[image]Following my problem: I have a theoretical model for my PSD, based on which I calculate a timeseries. This timeseries shall, after some modifications, be backtransformed into my PSD. Unfortunately, I don't get my original PSD back, but a slightly different one, and I have no clue why...

Here is my some illustrative code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = [1,2,3,4,5,6] #spots in the frequency domain
PSD = [7,8,7,10,6,3]
plt.loglog(bins, PSD)

t = np.linspace(0,1,2**9, endpoint = 'false')
signal = np.zeros_like(t)

for i in range(6):
signal += np.sqrt(PSD[i]) * np.cos(2*np.pi* t * bins[i] + random.uniform(0,2*np.pi))

n = signal.size
timestep = t[1]-t[0]
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep)
freq = freq[:freq.size/2]
PSD_from_timeserie = abs(scipy.fftpack.fft(signal)/ n * 2)**2
PSD_from_timeserie = PSD_from_timeserie[:PSD_from_timeserie.size/2]
plt.loglog(freq, PSD_from_timeserie, 'x') 
plt.show()
```

This almost gives the correct PSD, as you can check out easily...any suggestions on where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

it hast to be

```
t = np.linspace(0,1,2**9, endpoint = False)
```

with uppercase and with '... unfo numpy doesnt throw an error, but this way it works ;)'